# The resizing of svg

Tags: html, svg, geometry

I have a problem with my svg. I want to understand why the resizing doesn't work.
This is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Titel der Seite | Name der Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hier ist das Training von SVG</h1>

    <svg width ="1000" hight ="1000">

<circle r ="100" cx="200" cy="110" fill="#EC7357" stroke= "black" stroke-width = "2px"/>

    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Running this code, the circle will be cutte. How can I change this in order to see the whole cirle?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a spelling error is the cause of your height not being applied. "hight" should be "height". This will make sure that your height attribute gets applied to the element.

Comment: You're welcome! Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes. Keep at it! :)